# Create NSManagedObject subclass file in Xcode 3.2.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am just learning Core Data on iPhone and the [tutorial](http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/08/core-data-part-2-the-data-model.html) I am following says to create a new file and select `NSManagedObject` as the template. However, in Xcode 3.2.2 it seems to be gone.  Is there any way to get it back or some kind of workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the entity in your Core Data model (`xcdatamodel`) file first, and then create a new file. The managed object template should show up.

Comment: This is one of those things I can never remember and always end up Googling. Thanks Alex (and boo to Apple for the crappy non-obvious interface!)